# Given $a\in \mathbb Z$ and a prime number $p\neq 2 $, when is $x^{p^{2}} \equiv a (\text{mod} \, p^{j}) $ solvable.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given an $a\in \mathbb Z$ and a prime number $p \neq 2 $, I want to know when is $x^{p^{2}} \equiv a (\text{mod}\, p^{j}$ ) solvable for all $j \geq 1 $.

I came up with a proof that given an $a\in \mathbb Z$ and a prime  $p\neq 2 $, $ x^{p} \equiv a (\text{mod}\ p^{j})$ is solvable if and only if $x^{p} \equiv a  (\text{mod}\ p^{2}$) is solvable. My question is to do similar thing with $p^{2}$-th power, rather than just p-th power.

I have a hunch that even for my question, solution modulo $p^{2}$ should be enough. However, the proof I had for p-th power does not seem to generalize to $p^{2}$-th power. This makes me wonder if my hunch is wrong.

Comment: Your (reasonable) hunch turns out not to be correct—look at the $9$th powers modulo $27$ for example. I believe that solvability modulo $p^3$ is enough (at the very least when $p\nmid a$). One perspective: since the group of reduced residue classes modulo $p^j$ is cyclic of order $p^{j-1}(p-1)$, the congruence $x^{p^2}\equiv a\pmod{p^j}$ is "isomorphic" to the congruence $p^2 n \equiv d \pmod{p^{j-1}(p-1)}$ where $n$ and $d$ are the discrete logarithms of $x$ and $a$. This latter congruence has $p-1$ solutions when $j=2$ but $p^{j-3}(p-1)$ solutions when $j\ge3$, showing that $j=2$ is special.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you very much. I somehow was able to modify my proof for p-th powers to show that your belief was true. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For $p$ odd prime, given $p\nmid a$, let $ab\equiv 1\bmod p$ and $c=ab^{p^2}$ then $c\equiv 1\bmod p$.

$\{ (1+pu)^{p^2}\bmod p^j\} = \{ 1+p^3 v\bmod p^j\}$ so that

> There is a solution for $x^{p^2}\equiv a\bmod p^j$ iff there is one for $(1+pu)^{p^2}\equiv c\bmod p^j$ iff $c\equiv 1\bmod p^3$.